# i want to make onclick this function how can i make it?

Tags: javascript

When the mouse hovers over the bottom of the form, but I want to swim time it comes clicked

```
 $("document").ready(function () {

                 $(".secenek-alani .secenek-sol-taraf").mouseover(function () {
                     $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-1").css("display","block")            
                 })

                 $(".secenek-alani .secenek-sol-taraf").mouseleave(function () {
                     $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-1").css("display", "none")
                 })

                 $(".secenek-alani .secenek-sag-taraf").mouseover(function () {
                     $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-2").css("display", "block")
                 })

                 $(".secenek-alani .secenek-sag-taraf").mouseleave(function () {
                     $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-2").css("display", "none")
                 })
             })
```

Comment: Try first to change the language of your question...

Comment: Questions must be made in English

Comment: Something tells me "swim time" was not a good translation.

Answer (score 1):

change `$('#id')` to selector what you need? for example element id on witch you click.

```
$('#id').click(function(){
$(".secenek-alani .secenek-sol-taraf").mouseover(function ()     {
    $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-1").css("display","block")            
             })

             $(".secenek-alani .secenek-sol-taraf").mouseleave(function () {
                 $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-1").css("display", "none")
             })

             $(".secenek-alani .secenek-sag-taraf").mouseover(function () {
                 $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-2").css("display", "block")
             })

             $(".secenek-alani .secenek-sag-taraf").mouseleave(function () {
                 $(".secenek-alani .hesap-alani-2").css("display", "none")
             });

});
```